# Kodi Black Screen, Not responding to turning off Hardware Acceleration

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, kodi

Wits end is coming.

I've installed Kodi on my Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian hooked up to a Samsung UE46EH5000 (non-smart, non-cec) TV running at 1920x1080 resolution. When playing a video of any type, I get black screen (menu overlays are all there, just no content), sometimes audio, sometimes a freeze at 0:0:0. And sometimes a spinning ranbow grid centre screen (not the PI low power rainbow grid upper right: I had that for a while but I upgraded power supply).

So far I've tried:
--Turning off all Hardware Acceleration

--Switching from MMAL player to OMXPLayer

--Switched HDMI Cable

--Removing all add-ons I've added

--Clean install (including killing the .kodi/userdata directory) no additional 
addons

--Upgraded power supply to 2.4 amps

--Turning on Adjust display refresh rate

--Turning on Sync playback to display

I put the [log file in its entirety here.](http://www.brian-fitzgerald.net/kodi/kodi.log)

The suspect bits I see are:

> ERROR: CMMALRenderer::init_vout Failed to vout enable input port (status=1 ENOMEM)
>   08:02:26 T:1611121584   ERROR: OutputPicture - failed to configure renderer
>
> NOTICE:  fps: 23.976024, pwidth: 624, pheight: 352, dwidth: 624, dheight: 352
>   08:04:44 T:1038087088  NOTICE: Display resolution DESKTOP : 1920x1080 (1280x720) @ 60.00 - Full Screen (16)
>
> 08:04:47 T:1936716720   ERROR: COMXCoreComponent::EmptyThisBuffer component(OMX.broadcom.audio_mixer) - failed with result(0x80001018)
>   08:04:47 T:1936716720   ERROR: CActiveAEResamplePi::Resample OMX_EmptyThisBuffer() failed with result(0x80001018)

On startup, Kodi iniitalizes the Pulse 8 add on for CEC support -- as I don't have CEC, I thought about disabling this, but haven't found a way to do that. Guidance on that or any other theories about why Kodi isn't working would be welcome.

Comment: What type of video file are you trying to play? Have you checked the files play correctly on your computer? What about a fresh install of Kodi? It could be some important files got corrupted at some point.

Comment: Tried .mkv, .avi -- known good files from a usb drive I regularly plug straight into the TV. And I've now done two fresh installs, one of Kodi and another of the entire raspbian OS.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the USB drive? What sort of drive is it? Have you tried playing files off the SD card, or using a program like YouTube?

Comment: Ah, good thought -- it's an old Seagate external drive with its own power source. But just tried playing from a USB stick and the SD card, no change.

Comment: I had something similar; the reason seems to have been a broken `kodi` package. Re-running `aptitude safe-upgrade` resp. `dpkg-reconfigure kodi` solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

> ERROR: CMMALRenderer::init_vout Failed to vout enable input port (status=1 ENOMEM)

Try editing into your `/boot/config.txt`:

```
gpu_mem_1024 = 128
```

If that does not work, increase the number to 256; the default is 64 and the units are MB of RAM dedicated for use by the GPU (so you probably want to do this in conjunction with a "hardware acceleration enabled" setup).

If 256 does not solve the problem, then this is not the issue.

Comment: Thanks. Tried each setting, rebooted, and toggling hardware acceleration between default settings and none, no change.

Answer (score 1):

After several days of fiddling, I took the nuclear option and installed OpenElec instead of Raspbian. Night and Day. Up and running flawlessly in 5 minutes.

Comment: This is route I took as well.  Wish there was a better answer, since I need to be able to use a web browser, which IIRC is not supported in OpenElec.  I'm dual booting with Raspbian to run the browser, but it isn't ideal.

Comment: brianfit +1
I had the same problem with Raspbian+Kodi.
Changed to LibreELEC and all worked fine. LibreElec is an OpenElec fork so it should work too. I liked idea of having a flexible linux but my main use is video so... raspbian't.